# Auto type from input to textarea and wrap text in textarea?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, input, textarea

While I am typing in this input field:

```
<fieldset class="usp-title">
  <label for="user-submitted-title"><?php esc_html_e('Search', 'usp'); ?></label>
  <input id="user-submitted-title" 
         name="user-submitted-title" 
         type="text" 
         value="" 
         placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e('Search', 'usp'); ?>"<?php if (usp_check_required('usp_title')) echo $usp_required; ?> class="usp-input">
</fieldset>
```

I want it to automaticly type in this field, but text in here should be sorrounded by tags:

```
<fieldset class="usp-content">
  <?php if ($usp_options['usp_richtext_editor'] == true) { ?>

  <div class="usp_text-editor">
    <?php $usp_rte_settings = array(
      'wpautop' => true,  // enable rich text editor
      'media_buttons' => true,  // enable add media button
      'textarea_name' => 'user-submitted-content', // name
      'textarea_rows' => '10',  // number of textarea rows
      'tabindex' => '',    // tabindex
      'editor_css' => '',    // extra CSS
      'editor_class' => 'usp-rich-textarea', // class
      'teeny' => false, // output minimal editor config
      'dfw' => false, // replace fullscreen with DFW
      'tinymce' => true,  // enable TinyMCE
      'quicktags' => true,  // enable quicktags
      'drag_drop_upload' => true,  // enable drag-drop
    );
    $usp_rte_settings = apply_filters('usp_editor_settings', $usp_rte_settings);
    $usp_editor_content = apply_filters('usp_editor_content', '');
    wp_editor($usp_editor_content, 'uspcontent', $usp_rte_settings); ?>
  </div>
  <?php } else { ?>

    <label for="user-submitted-content"><?php esc_html_e('Post Content', 'usp'); ?></label>
    <textarea id="user-submitted-content" name="user-submitted-content" rows="5" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e('Post Content', 'usp'); ?>"<?php if (usp_check_required('usp_content')) echo $usp_required; ?> class="usp-textarea"></textarea>
        <?php } ?>

</fieldset>
```

Second field should get text sorrounded by `[bbcode]copied from input[bbcode]`

Comment: Use .keydown event and when it's completed just upload the value from one textbox to the other while appending the tags around the variable

Comment: I tried, but I did not suceed, can you write code for me please. I am not good in coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// When the user types a letter

$("#user-submitted-title").keyup(function(){
  // Grab the value, append the tags and drop it into the textarea
  $("#user-submitted-content").val("[bbcode]"+$(this).val()+"[bbcode]"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a keyup event to the 'from' textbox and set the value of the 'to' textbox/area

```js
$('#user-submitted-title').on('keyup',function(e){
  $('#user-submitted-content').val('[bbcode]'+ $(this).val() +'[bbcode]');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='user-submitted-title'/>
<textarea id='user-submitted-content'></textarea>
```